# Build .jar file instead of .war file

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, devops

following a DevOps Course using Jenkins - Maven,
steps:

- job getting repo from github --- Success.
- job package with maven --- Success, But always as a .jar file not .war file.
- job Deploy into tomcat 9 --- Failure, Becase cant find .war file.

what can i do so Package will be with .war file not .jar file.
is there a Configuration i can use.
so beginner with Java.
grateful with any tips.

Tried to change many pom.xml files.
Tried to change configs into pom files.
Not much still Beginner for Java.

Comment: Share us the pom or the entire repository. Not always the apps could be packaged as jar or war

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a WAR you need two things:

1. You must have `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your pom.xml. If nothing has been specified, Maven assumes the packaging type is a jar.

```
<project>
  ...
  <groupId>com.example.projects</groupId>
  <artifactId>documentedproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
```

2. Your project must follow this structure (unless you configure the plugin to use a different structure, but i guess you aren´t)

```
 |-- pom.xml
 `-- src
     `-- main
         |-- java
         |   `-- com
         |       `-- example
         |           `-- projects
         |               `-- SampleAction.java
         |-- resources
         |   `-- images
         |       `-- sampleimage.jpg
         `-- webapp
             |-- WEB-INF
             |   `-- web.xml
             |-- index.jsp
             `-- jsp
                 `-- websource.jsp
```

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html for more info.